# Prove or disprove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-l}{x_n-l}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$, $l=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove or disprove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{x_{n+1}-l}{x_n-l}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}\right)$$ where $l=\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$

I think that the above result is true,but I am not really sure how to prove it.If anyone has a counterexample I am looking forward to it.
EDIT1 : $x_n$ is any real sequence which is not constant.
EDIT2: What if we add the additional constraint that $l \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047760/prove-or-disprove-that-there-always-exists-a-sequence-satisfying-a-relation-with I reasked the question with some changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_n=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n}$, for which $l=2$ and $$\lim\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=1$$ and $$\lim\frac{x_{n+1}-2}{x_n-2}=\frac12.$$

Comment: Question means, whether for any real value of $l$ there exist a sequence $x_n$ which satisfies the given condition.

Comment: @LoveInvariants The OP also seems to be happy with a counter-example :-)

Comment: Actually a counter-example is what I want,thank you,excellent job.

Comment: Haha thats what I answered. But you know your counter example is not perfect. You have to choose the value of l and then define a sequence. I think there exists infinite of sequence for a value of l and you quoted one of them. But hey its ok if OP is happy. Anyways I will post a question for discussion.

Comment: I guess I should think more of your comment and the question. I will come back to it if I find something better :-) Thank you!

Comment: The counter-example here is perfectly fine: either it works for all $\ell$ or it doesn't work for all $\ell$ (and that's the question). Anyway one can easily just change $2\to \frac{1}{\ell}$ to get a counter-example that works for all $0 < \ell < 1$.

Comment: ...and just for completeness $x_n = \ell\frac{2^{2^n}-1}{2^{2^n}}$ works for all $\ell\not= 0$. As $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = 1 + 2^{-2^n}$ and $\frac{x_{n+1}-\ell}{x_n - \ell} = 2^{-2^n}$.

Comment: @Winther: nice one!

Comment: @Winther- I dub the question like this. For a certain value of $l$ does there exist a sequence which satisfies the given criteria. And that can't be countered until you disprove it generally. That is the reason why I'm worried. Why the OP asks for a counter?

Comment: @LoveInvariants As $\ell$ is not specified it’s usually assumed in these kinds of questions that this is a general statement to be proven or disproven for which a single counter-example suffices. But it does hold for $\ell = 0$ (trivially) so I guess it’s also natural to interpret it as to find all values of $\ell$ for which it holds and fails.

Comment: @Winther- Whats the problem in my solution then? I think its also the same as this one.

Comment: @LoveInvariants The problem is that $l = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} n $ does not exist ($\infty$ is not a real number!). The expression $\frac{x_{n+1}-l}{x_n-l}$ is therefore ill defined for every $n$ so it doesn't make sense to ask for equal of the two limits in this case. The value $l$ has to be a real number here.

Comment: @Winther- I got a feeling for infinity being real number in this particular problem.I think $\infty$ is some sort of extended real number. As given on wikipedia we can use infinity as number in real analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x_n=n$
Then LHS=$1\over0$ and RHS=$1+{1\over\infty}=1$
Both aren't equal.

Comment: Note that the question implicitly assumes that $\ell = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ exists

Comment: Do you mean $l$ is a constant? It is nowhere written though about that.