# Prove or disprove that there always exists a sequence satisfying a relation with a real constant $k$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

**Question:**

> Prove or disprove for a real number $k$ there always exists a sequence $x_n$ where $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=k$ and $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-k}{x_n-k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$$
>     Here I'm interested in a proof. This will not have a counter example as all 
>   possible sequences are to be considered.

Tell me if I can do something to improve the question.

**Post Script:**
This question is a mere work of curiosity and is inspired by a question put up on this website. It is not duplicate and is slightly different from the original one.
 [Anyways here is the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047670/prove-or-disprove-that-lim-n-to-infty-fracx-n1-lx-n-l-lim-n-to-in/3047693?noredirect=1#comment6282746_3047693)

Comment: Did you mean to say $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=k$? Also, what is $l$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Here series is defined by the constant $k$ and sorry for that $l$

Comment: There's a part where you wrote just $\lim_{n\to \infty}=k$. Shouldn't it be $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=k$?

Comment: Oh yep...........

Comment: $$x_n=k+ \frac{1}{n}$$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the sequence 
$$
x_n = k+\frac 1n
$$
We clearly have $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=k$ and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}-k}{x_n -k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac n{n+1} = 1 = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{k+\frac 1{n+1}}{k+\frac 1{n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} .
$$